# Custom Admin Login Form [Form_Key Error]

Tags: magento-1.9, form-key, admin-login

> I have located the problem precisely but I don't know how to solve it.

When I'm on my **custom cms page** with my **new admin login form**, Magento gives me a different key_form than my default admin login page.

So when I try to login with my custom form, Magento redirects me to my default admin login page and warns me with the following message `Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page.`

***My Frontend Custom CMS Admin Login Page:***

```
<input name="form_key" value="cbzRGF9ccU8Ac8Ib"/>
```

***My Backend Default Admin Login Page:***

```
<input name="form_key" value="B9O7srzwq7utjQ79"/>
```

> How to generate a form_key on my custom Login page that will be the
>   same as my default admin login form (www.website.com/admin).

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this to create a URL with a valid form key:

`$path = "admin/sales_order";
 $adminURL = Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl($path);`

Just change the variable `path` to the path you need in your admin panel.

I am assuming you already did that, but to access an admin URL you need to be logged in with a valid Magento Admin account. You can use this code to log in:

```
$adminUser = Mage::getModel('admin/user');
$username = "USERNAME";
$password = "PASSWORD";

if ($adminUser->authenticate($username, $password)){
    //Your actions if valid login
}
```

Comment: Bruno, thanks for your help but your solution is not good. The form_key generated on my custom cms page is not the same that of my default admin panel.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that the key is generated by Magento, so there is no way to have the exact same key. But you can still have a valid one that works. Is your admin panel not working with the generated key?